# Data structure usage

Tags: java, data-structures

I recently faced a question where I need to display the last n lines in a file in java. It is similar to implementing tail function of unix in java but I just have readline() method and a method to check the end of file. No other methods. I was thinking of an approach with Queue data structure like this:

- Read n lines starting from the first line of the file.
- store the n lines read in the queue.
- Check if we have reached the end of file. If yes, print the contents of the queue.
- If not, read n more lines and push them in the queue.

Can anyone think of any other approach?

Comment: Read the stream backwards

Comment: Backward reading is also not an option allowed.

Comment: Your algorithm fails if the number of lines is not a multiple of n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a ring buffer of size n where you override the oldest entry?
It would basically look like the code below. I made up the functions to read the file but you should get the idea.

```
String[] lines = new String[n];
int i = 0;
while(!file.eof()) {
  String line = file.readLine();
  lines[i] = line;
  i = (i + 1) % n;
}

for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  if (lines[i] != null) {
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
  }
  i = (i + 1) % n;
}
```